# C++ #include for a third-party API - Can never find some headers

Tags: c++, qt

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to use third party API.

I'm using QT 5.3.1 / QT Creator 3.1.2

And I want to include the necessary headers for Nvidia's SceniX which can be found here: https://developer.nvidia.com/scenix

I have Bjarne Stroustrup's fourth edition the C++ programming language and looked up include in the index and all 4 entries gave worthless information, and if looking up what I want by the index doesn't get the right answer then I have no idea how to use the book and google isn't giving anything useful either. I have also tried reading heaps of answers here but are all ultimately irrelevant and just end up in spending time for nothing.

The directory structure is something like the following but is trimmed.. a lot:

```
-root
    -inc
        -nvsg
            -nvsg
                -nvsg.h
            -nvgl
                -nvgl.h
```

Showing my code doesn't mean much because I've tried a hundred different iterations, but currently it goes like this..

```
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    inc/nvsg/nvsg/nvsg.h \
```

But no matter what I do, it will NOT find the header when I try to include it, it's as if it isn't even there. Auto-complete doesn't even see it.

But sometimes when I include things from other folders they work. It simply doesn't follow any form of logic.

Comment: How do you include it? With `#include "header.h"` or `#include <header.h>`?

Comment: #include <header.h> but using quotes wont find it either

Comment: Did you include the dir (`-I<dir>`) during compiling?

Comment: I think you have to do in your project file: `INCLUDEPATH += inc/nvsg/nvsg` and in your source files: `#include <nvsg.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add the third-party .h files in `HEADERS`. These files are YOUR headerfiles. Add the includepath for these .h files to `INCLUDEPATH += inc/nvsg` and use in your cpp code:

```
#include <nvgl/nvgl.h>
#include <nvsg/nvsg.h>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that did the trick. Just trying to get my head around the differences between C++ and the other languages, the concepts sure are different. I have two more questions in same topic before I mark correct answer if you can; for third-party .cpp files do i add these in sources or, how do I handle them - how does compiler find them? also the third party files have their own includes that point to the dir they're in and always report wrong, i can modify the files but prefer not to if it can be helped

Comment: To explain it in a simple way, let's say .cpp and .h are in the same folder. When you compile, you have two steps: compiling (generate object) and linking (link objects between us) and you have your executable (or your library). To use external programs (third-party), you can either add every source in your project and compile all in once or you can compile it before and in your project, you only mention where to find your headers (with INCLUDEPATH) and your objects (or libraries with keyword LIBS). Hard to explain compile process in 500 characters ^^.

Comment: ``SOURCES`` are your .cpp sources files (if have 3rd party sources add them in a subdirectory). ``HEADERS`` are your .h header files (same as sources but headers). ``INCLUDEPATH`` is the absolute path where headerfiles and their relative path (``#include <relative/path/includefile.h>``) are being searched for. ``LIBS`` define which libraries to link against (``LIBS += -Lpath/to/lib -llibararyName``). This is Qt pro-file specific. Probably every compiler/linker wants to have ``-I`` Include paths, ``-L`` libary paths, ``-l`` libary files or similar parameters.